# how can we get to know when the session completed when it is cofigured as run continuosly

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have scheduled my workflow to run continuosly and it was partition enabled one. There are 5 sessions presents in my workflow and I want to do some actions after the session gets completed.

Since i configured this as Run Continuosly it will not go to the succeeded status and it will be always in running status only. But I want here to do some post session success tasks after the each session successfully completed its process.

Thanks in advance
Velva

Comment: You have posted a few questions so far and got some answers. Were they good? Did they help you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sessions are not marked for run-continuously, workflows are.
2. Even though workflow is running continuously, the sessions can still have pre and post session tasks.  that should be your solution.

Comment: Thanks Raghav! Colud you please tell me how to release the completed session holding memroy? Once the session completed its running I want to make that session releases the memory which it holds for processing. Thsi is the action I have to do after the successful completeion of each session.

Comment: thats automatically managed by Informatica. You dont/cant do anything specifically for releasing memory. Remember, you are dealing with a pre-built tool, not a programming lanaguage...

Comment: yeah correct. but the problem here is it is not automatically releasing the memory. It could be the product issue with informatica. So that is the reason why i am trying to do this memory releasing through post session command.